# How to check whether a insert operation is successful or not in C# Windows Phone App with SQLitePCL

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, insert

I'm using `SQLitePCL`for local database in my Windows Phone App. I need to check whether a `insert operation` in the database is successful or failed. How can I check that?

I'm trying following snippet for inserting:

```
using ( var connection = new SQLiteConnection(DbController.DB_NAME))
{
    using( var statemant = connection.Prepare(sql)) //sql is the string containing SQL command prepared earlier
    {
        statemant.Step();
    }
}
```

I don't find any property or method in the `statement` object that contains the success status.  Is there any way to get the success status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`statemant.Step()` should return an [`SQLiteResult` enum](https://sqlitepcl.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/SQLitePCL/SQLitePCL/SQLiteResult.cs). You can check if the result is equal to `OK`.

```
SQLiteResult result = statemant.Step();
if(result != SQLiteResult.OK)
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```